# WAMP - mod_rewrite still doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have a problem with mod_rewrite module.

It doesn't work, I made a .htaccess file in the same directory with index.html, and when I'am trying to do something I get error 404.

When I am checking with phpinfo() function - it shows that mod_rewrite is loaded.

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from All

</Directory>

#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```

Comment: Show us your .htaccess

Comment: I made a empty folder and put there only .httacces then I wrote a random characters like "sjlkjdaslkd;". Shouldn't it show any error? Like 400. It doesn't react.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some basic reading on what mod_rewrite and htaccess is. `http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/`